# Formal proving of languages accepted by a finite automata.

Tags: intuition, automata

Suppose $L_1 \cup L_2,L_1 \subseteq E^* $ are languages accepted by finite automata and $L_1\cap L_2 =\emptyset $. We need to prove that $L_2 $ is also accepted by a finite automaton.

So I've started with building an intuition, but I have a few questions.

1. Say I've found an automaton presumably representing a language. What's the proper way of proving that it actually is a representation of the language?
2. Is it enough to prove that, given all of the above, $L_2$ has a regular expression (since both $L_1 \cup L_2$ and $ L_1$ should have regular expressions)? Or is that a wrong way of looking at this kind of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a language $M$ is regular, then $\overline{M}=E^*\setminus M$ is regular too. Therefore
$$
L_2=\overline{\overline{L_1\cup L_2}\cup L_1}
$$
is regular.

Comment: Thanks, But i didn't look for an easy answer. I was [And still] trying to understand the ideas behind how to formaly prove everything writted above.

Comment: Then you have to construct an automaton following the Kleene Theorem from the formula in my answer.